# search and replace multiple occurrences

Tags: bash, shell, sed

So I have a file containing millions of lines.
and now within the file I have occurrences such as

```
=Continent
=Country
=State
=City
=Street
```

Now I have an excel file in which I have the text that should replace these occurrences - as an example  :
**=Continent** should be replaced with **=Asia**
Similarly for other text

Now I was thinking of writing a java program to read my input file , read the mapping file and for each occurrence search and replace.
I am being lazy here - was wondering if I could do the same using editors like VIM   ?
would that be possible ?
NOTE - I dont want to do a single text replace - I have multiple text that need to be found and replaced and I dont want to do the search and replace manually for each.

**EDIT1:**
Contents of my file that I want to replace: "**1.txt**"

```
continent=cont_text
country=country_text
```

The file that contains the values I want to replace with : "**to_replace.txt**"

```
=cont_text~Asia
=country_text~India
```

and finally using 'sed' here is my .sh file - but I am doing something wrong - it does not replace the contents of "1.txt"

```
while IFS="~" read foo bar;
do
echo $foo
echo $bar
for filename in 1.txt; do
    sed -i.backup 's/$foo/$bar/g;' $filename
done
done < to_replace.txt
```

Comment: For starters, you could at least export the text from your excel file to some sane format (csv?), load it in a Vim buffer or save it to a file and show us a sample. Or, you can make the problem even more complicated by stating that your excel file has an unknown password and is located on a different machine that you can't connect to :P

Comment: :) please see my edit with complete details - tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put `$foo` and `$bar` in single quotes because the shell won't expand them. You don't need the `for $filename in 1.txt` loop because `sed` will loop through the lines of `1.txt`. And you can't use `-i.backup` inside the loop because it will change the backup file each time and not preserve the original. So your script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp 1.txt 1.txt.backup
while IFS="~" read foo bar;
do
    echo $foo
    echo $bar
    sed -i "s/$foo/=$bar/g;" 1.txt
done < to_replace.txt
```

Output:

```
$ cat 1.txt
continent=Asia
country=India
```

Comment: That will fail in various interesting ways depending on the contents of your input files and the contents of directory you execute it from. Any time you write a loop in shell to manipulate text you have the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines and shell is an environment from which to call tools not a tool to manipulate text so any time you write a shell loop to manipulate text you are doing it wrong.

Just use the tool that the same guys who invented sed and shell also invented to do general text processing jobs like this, awk:

```
$ awk -F'[=~]' -v OFS="=" 'NR==FNR{map[$2]=$3;next} {$2=map[$2]} 1' to_replace.txt 1.txt
continent=Asia
country=India
```

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` command will do it without any loop:

```
sed -n 's#\(^=[^~]*\)~\(.*\)#s/\1/=\2/g#p' to_replace.txt |sed -i -f- 1.txt
```

Or `sed` with extended regex:

```
sed -nr 's#(^=[^~]*)~(.*)#s/\1/=\2/g#p' to_replace.txt | sed -i -f- 1.txt
```

**Explanation:**

The `sed` command:

```
sed -n 's#\(^=[^~]*\)~\(.*\)#s/\1/=\2/g#p' to_replace.txt
```

generates an output:

```
s/=cont_text/=Asia/g
s/=country_text/=India/g
```

which is then used as a `sed` script for the next `sed` after the pipe.

---

```
$ cat 1.txt
continent=Asia
country=India
```